# Iterate over variables in spss and get a conditional sum

Tags: python

I have the following variables:
`attribute1 , value1, attribute2, value2`, ...

Each attribute can have a numeric value between 0 and 6.

How can I iterate over the variables and get the sum for each attribute?

Like: get sum of all values where `attribute == 0`?

Comment: Surely the sum of values where the attribute is 0 is... 0? Or do you mean the *count*? Either way, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.

Comment: That hasn't clarified anything. Give a [mcve] of your code with inputs and expected and actual outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your variable storage, so I'll assume a list of tuples.

Use a list comprehension:

```
listOfTuples = [(2, 5), (4, 3), (2, 4), (2, 3)] # etc...

someValue = 2 # Your desired value

# Store the VALUE - not the key
sumOfAttrsForAValue = sum([y for x, y in listOfTuples if x == someValue])

print (sumOfAttrsForAValue)

# 12
```

Comment: @ManuKaracho that's not code. Are you talking about data in a file? Edit the question!